# Failure remediation strategy for File I/O

Tags: c, file, file-io

I'm doing buffered IO into a file, both read and write.  I'm using `fopen(), fseeko()`, standard ANSI C file I/O functions.  In all cases, I'm  writing to  a standard local file on a disk.  How often do these file I/O operations fail, and what should the strategy be for failures?  I'm not exactly looking for stats, but I'm looking for a general purpose statement on how far I should go to handle error conditions.

For instance, I think everyone recognizes that `malloc()` could and probably will fail someday on some user's machine and the developer should check for a NULL being returned, but there is no great remediation strategy since it probably means the system is out of memory.  At least, this seems to be the approach taken with `malloc()` on desktop systems, embedded systems are different.

Likewise, is it worth reattempting a file I/O operation, or should I just consider a failure to be basically unrecoverable, etc.

I would appreciate some code samples demonstrating proper usage, or a library guide reference that indicates how this is to be handled.  Any other data is, of course, welcome.

Comment: Good question. When writes fail it usually means the file system is full. I've seen code that tries to address and asks the user to make some space. This was a CAD program that created huge files back when disks were small so that was a reasonable expectation.

Comment: If your program has any kind of user interface, it's worth prompting for retry in a loop.  The most common write failures occur when a file is open in another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're a novice programmer here.  The advice I give here is not applicable in all situations, but it will help you write solid code.

- Trying to figure out how to recover from an error is *hard* unless you have a very solid model for how that error can occur and what it means.
- Consequently, unless you know exactly what an error is and what it means, report the error on `stderr` or whathaveyou and bomb out.
- If you bomb out as soon as the first thing goes awry, you will be forced to understand the error and fix your code.  This leads to higher-quality code in the long run, even if your intuition suggests otherwise.
- Some functions return "errors" that don't indicate serious failure.  In POSIX, `EINTR` is there as a hack to make signal handling easier to implement, and it has the side effect of making a certain architecture of single-threaded programs that care about signals a little easier to implement.  When I/O functions return `EAGAIN`, that means you have the file open in nonblocking mode and an I/O wanted to block.  You need to handle these things correctly.
- Some errors indicate that something awful has happened; `EIO` in POSIX means that something has gone wrong that the function doesn't even know how to talk about.
- Working with file-system code, you'll notice that some errors can be caused by concurrent updates to the file.  It is a fool's errand to try to "recover" from these sorts of things "gracefully."  Don't try.

Comment: I don't think EINTR is a hack.Even if there are popular articles supporting that claim. A program should be interruptible any time (Control-C, for example).

Comment: @JoSo: You have confused `EINTR` with `SIGINT`.  ^C sends `SIGINT`.  `EINTR` happens when a signal got delivered during a blocking system call.

Comment: EINTR is exactly what you get when you were interrupted by a SIGINT (unless you haven't installed a signal handler in which case your program is terminated).

Comment: @JoSo: It's also what you get when any number of benign things that are irrelevant to your program logic happens.  You'll notice that the APIs are inconsistent about what can return `EINTR` and what can't.  For instance, `sem_wait` can while `pthread_mutex_lock` cannot.

Comment: Yes, there's the notion of "slow" device which has to be created. Read up on `signal(7)`

Comment: I'd like to add that certainly not all cases may be clear. For example, I've spent considerable time in my life waiting for an `ls` on a stale NFS mount to finish because it was uninterruptible. But nevertheless, EINTR is a good thing. If you don't want to handle it, just wrap it like `while((r = read(...)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)`

Comment: No, not a novice, but you had some good thoughts and I think your answer was most helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of my far-to-quick downvoted answer, trying to give it another chance.

That depends very heavily on the type of program.

As a prominent example, Glib, a popular C library doesn't event care to handle OOM; it just aborts. This may be appropriate for application code, but it's not for some system-level code.

In most cases, situations as I/O error or OOM can be assumed to be inescapable. For example, many programs encountering OOM are have very sequential (few branches) codepaths and don't have alternatives on a failed allocation. Thus, most programs will just exit(1).

If you on the other side are manipulating sensible state, you should do your best to not crash or exit.

Cleaning up though is often difficult, especially in plain C.

As a sensible minimum, you should always try to investigate the immediate reason for failure and print that to stderr -- it helps debugging.

I can recommend reading the source code of reprepro which is very careful in handling error conditions and cleaning up. It's a great deal of boiler plate, so you might choose it does not fit your application after reading that.